# How to limit hot water temperature if your boiler doesn't have this control?

Tags: water, temperatures

We have 20 month twins who can almost reach taps in the bathroom.  Our hotwater system is fixed at 55°C.  It feels too hot for them, and it's not adjustable.

How have other parents managed this?  I don't want them to burn themselves, but I'm no great plumber either, and replacing our taps (faucets in the US) would be expensive and complex...

Comment: Good question. Are you talking about sink taps, bathtub taps, or both?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all water heating systems, so please forgive my question. Do you have a hot water tank? Tanks themselves are not costly to replace.

Comment: It's a combi-boiler, so it makes instant hot water and central heating, so there is no large tank.  Erica - I guess I'm talking about both..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your taps are like, but replacing them with thermostatic ones is normally not that expensive and you'll have years of benefits from them. They are **the** way to make your taps safer, so I would really consider saving up for at least the bath/shower tap.

The ones available in the Netherlands (and presumably all over the world) have a button-lock to prevent accidentally setting the temperature above 38 C. This will prevent little accidents (especially in the shower) long after your children understand that the hot water is dangerous. Try these out when selecting one, as some models are too easy to unlock when just grabbing and rotating the knob.

The luxury models also prevent the metal of the tap itself from getting hot by having the cold water flow under the surface of the tap. This is for those occasions when your children grab the tap to keep their balance or get up out of a bath.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't limit the temperature at the boiler,  then one option that you can investigate is having a thermostatic compensating valve installed where the hot water outlets the boiler to feed the house. This will require a plumber to install as it requires having a cold water line routed to mix with the hot - but that way all of the water throughout the house will have a controllable set maximum temperature and will be far cheaper then upgrading a bunch of nice faucets.

This assumes that the hot water that feeds the faucets is on a separate system and isn't also being routed to multiple radiators throughout the house used for heat. If it is all one connected system using hot water radiators on the same circuit then your only option is at the individual faucets - which can be a real pain for things like shower fittings.